# Given day, month and year, calculate weekending date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Given day, month and year as integer columns in the table, calculate the date and weekending date from these values.

I tried the following but it gives me an incorrect result for the derived date as '2022-08-05 00:00:00'

```
select to_date(2020||03||20,'YYYYMMDD')
```

Even tried below but results in a string without leading zeros for month and day

```
select  (cast (2020 as varchar)+cast (03 as varchar(2))+cast (02 as varchar(2)))
```

Result for above is : 202032

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide some sample inputs and their corresponding outputs that you would like to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have numbers -- so leading zeros are missing.  You can try:

```
select to_date('2020'||'03'||'20', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Or, if these have to be numbers:

```
select to_date( (2020 * 10000 + 03 * 100 + 20)::text, 'YYYYMMDD')
```